# Database is not visible through phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have my database and there are 200+ user data and website is made on Wordpress. The phpMyAdmin shows no database but it occupy 9.3Mb of space. I already made a backup but it shows no database selected.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the database from within phpMyAdmin, you're probably not logged in as the proper user. Due to the anonymous user that some MySQL installations come with, you may be able to connect as a nonexistent user. I suggest double-checking that the username and password you're using with phpMyAdmin do indeed correspond with actual MySQL users.

Comment: i click on phpMyAdmin icon in c-panel then it ask me additional login details and then when i provide the username and password it loged in but there is no database.

Comment: Right, in all likelihood it connects as the anonymous user. Try using a completely wrong username and see if you get the same behavior. Try asking your hosting provider for help verifying that you're using the correct username and password. If you have access from the command-line client, try using that to see if you can see your database.